# Sample Application on HttpClient with .NETCoreApp 1.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to send a Http request to some website(URL) and get a response(Basically I need to use GetAsync and PutAsync methods for this) and I need to do it with.NETCoreApp 1.1 in VS2017.

- Do get and post
- Setting headers
- Ignore TLS cert errors

Does anyone have a simple example how to achieve this?

I found this example in the API documentation [HttpClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-1.1), but it is not clear how to achieve the above points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spend a couple of hours looking at the source code [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) and came up with this simple example

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoreFxHttpClientHandlerTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
        }

        public static async Task<bool> Run()
        {
            var ignoreTls = true;

            using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                if (ignoreTls)
                {
                    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
                }

                using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
                {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://test.com/get"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
                    }

                    using (var httpContent = new StringContent("{ \"id\": \"4\" }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                    {
                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://test.com/api/users")
                        {
                            Content = httpContent
                        };
                        httpContent.Headers.Add("Cookie", "a:e");

                        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

See code in [github](https://github.com/Quobject/CoreFxHttpClientHandlerTest).